# compare java epoch string with php epoch date

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

here's I have a java string epoch date and i want to compare and add data to 
SQL it's giving a parse error don't know why any solution..

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
//Getting values
$number = $_POST['number'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$start = strtotime("now");
$end = strtotime("-7 days");
while($start->format('U') > $date->format('U') > $end->format('U')){

$sql = "INSERT INTO message_detail (number,type,date,content) VALUES  ('$number','$type','$date','$content')";

//Importing our db connection script
require_once('connect.php');

//Executing query to database
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
echo 'Entry Added Successfully';
}else{
echo 'Could Not Add Entry';
}
}
//Closing the database 
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: There are a few issues with your code as I see it. Firstly you are including the db connection script in a loop, secondly you are directly embedding variables in the sql thus leaving it open to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function returns an integer timestamp, not a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, so you can't call `format()` method like this way.

  ```
  $start = strtotime("now");
  $start->format('U');
  // etc. are wrong
  ```

  Instead, create a `DateTime` object and then call it's `format()` method, like this:

  ```
  $start = new DateTime("now");
  $start->format('U');
  // etc.
  ```
- Now comes to your issue,

  > it's giving a parse error

  That's because of your `while` condition,

  ```
  while($start->format('U') > $date->format('U') > $end->format('U')){ ...
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  <strike>May be, you want to do something like this:</strike>

  ```
  while($start->format('U') < $date->format('U') &&  $date->format('U') > $end->format('U')){

      // your code

  }
  ```

---

**Sidenotes:**

- There's no point including the connection handler in each iteration of the loop, so take this statement, `require_once('connect.php');` outside of your `while` loop.
- Learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection. Also see [how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

---

### Edited:

> i want to enter a data of only last 7 days from entry time...

If that's your requirement, then you can do this using either `strtotime()` function or `DateTime` class,

#### (1) Using strtotime() function

```
// your code

$content = $_POST['content'];
$start = strtotime("-7 days");
$date = strtotime($date);
$end = strtotime("now");
```

And there's no point using a `while` loop, a simple `if` condition will do just fine,

```
if($start <= $date &&  $end >= $date){

    // your code

}
```

#### (2) Using DateTime class

```
// your code

$content = $_POST['content'];
$start = new DateTime("-7 days");
$date = new DateTime($date);
$end = new DateTime("now");
```

And there's no point using a `while` loop, a simple `if` condition will do just fine,

```
if($start->format('U') <= $date->format('U') &&  $end->format('U') >= $date->format('U')){

    // your code

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rajdeep but i want to enter a data of only last 7 days from entry time so i have to use     strtotime() is there any other method available...??

Comment: @HirenGujarati I've edited my answer. Please see the **Edited** section of my answer.

Comment: hey @rajdeep it's giving error if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){ at this line called  mysqli_query(): Empty query in <b>/home/u336100496/public_html/call_detail/insert.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
Could Not Add EntryConnected successfully<br />

Comment: @HirenGujarati Have you constructed the query inside `if` block,like this: `$sql = "INSERT INTO message_detail ...`? I don't think so.